# Android - Moving camera to hard-coded coordinate on Google Maps varies by phone? Latitude only?

Tags: android, google-maps, coordinates

I'm making an Android app where, at one point, a Google map loads and zooms into a hard-coded coordinate (43.000962,-78.787808, in Buffalo, NY). The coordinate is read-in from a file, but essentially the code run in onMapReady() is:

```
map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(43.000962, -78.787808)));
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
```

I sampled this coordinate (for use in the code, not after the fact) using my LG G3 running google maps but it matches perfectly with Google Maps in a browser if I search the coordinate.

My problem is that it works on my phone (and someone else's G3 that I tested on), but for a Samsung Galaxy S4 the camera zooms in <1 mi north, and on a Samsung Galaxy S8+ it appears *approximately* at 36.9126157, -78.787808, which is in **Virgina**! The longitude isn't exactly -78.787808 (I had to guess based on a picture because I don't possess the phone for debugging), but maybe that has to do with geodesic coordinates (?). I don't have 100 different Android phones to test this with, but what I can gather from this small sample pool it that for some reason, the latitude is varying.

For reference, this is what it's supposed to look like (from my G3):

[image: 43.000962, -78.787808, Buffalo, NY]

And this is what happened with the S8+:

[image: 36.9126157, -78.787808, somewhere in Virginia]

But it gets weirder - after normal interaction by users, under a certain condition, the map will zoom to a *marker*, but this (so far) always works correctly.

**Why does moving the camera to a coordinate have drastically varying effects while moving the camera essentially to marker.getPosition() later does not?** Is there a difference between these things? Is it about timing? How can I fix this?

The only thing I can think of is that maybe it happens "too early" in onMapReady() but I have difficulty believing that's an issue. I remember though, seeing in the log something about having too much work on the main thread while loading the map, so maybe some kind of lag while rendering the map actually screws-up where the camera gets positioned. I also can't account for an unreasonable amount of work done anywhere in the Activity with the Google Map, but that might be a separate issue in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are moving the camera (`map.moveCamera`) and immediately animating it (`map.animateCamera`) and the animation is overriding the movement.

You can animate the camera to a given `LatLng` + `zoom` doing

```
map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.000962, -78.787808), 15f));
```

If you want to do it in two different steps you can use the `CameraUpdateAnimator` from my project `MapUtils` (https://github.com/antoniocarlon/MapUtils). You can do it like this:

```
// Create the animator object
// Note that you will need to pass an OnCameraIdleListener here
CameraUpdateAnimator animator = new CameraUpdateAnimator(map, mOnCameraIdleListener);

// Add animations
animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(43.000962, -78.787808)), false, 0);
animator.add(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15), true, 0);

// Execute the animation
animator.execute();
```

Comment: Ok, so I believe my issue was that before the map was "drawn" it was "ready" in onMapReady() and was recognizing touch gestures that interfered with the animation. I used the consecutive "moveCamera" and "animateCamera" statements as I saw in example after example, and never changed it as it appeared to work. In the answer you provide, you consolidate the statements into one, but using animateCamera seems to have worse effects for interrupting it ;). However, switching it to moveCamera seems to be the solution, so I'll accept your answer.